# JSON multi-series line chart update

Tags: graph, d3.js

I have a question with about d3. I'm using this multiline chart from here: 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Instead of using .tsv, I'm using two local json arrays in this format:

```
var myData = [
{
    "date": "20111002",
    "New York": "6",
    "San Francisco": "81",
    "Austin": "13"
},
{
    "date": "20111003",
    "New York": "30",
    "San Francisco": "37",
    "Austin": "33"
},
{
    "date": "20111004",
    "New York": "5",
    "San Francisco": "85",
    "Austin": "10"
}
]
```

I have a second json in the same format except I want to update the graph on html button onclick. Any help would be much appreciated. The trouble I'm having is that the line paths aren't being redrawn.

Comment: can you post the code that isn't working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take this as an example:
http://mpf.vis.ywng.cloudbees.net/

The code for updating the path of the curve is:

```
    fund.select("path").transition()
    .attr("d", function(d) { 
       if(d.vis=="1"){return line(d.priceList);} else{ return null;}
     })
```

You should use transition to trigger the changed, you can modify the return of the anonymous function to update the curve.

Comment: the link is now missing